# Do distillable states necessarily violate the CHSH inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

Let $\rho$ be a bipartite quantum state. If $\rho$ is [distillable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_distillation) will it necessarily violate the CHSH inequality ($|\langle A_0(B_0+B_1)+A_1(B_0-B_1)\rangle| \leq 2$)?

Comment: This will likely depend on what $A_i$ and $B_i$ are.  (E.g., do you restrict to qubits?)

Comment: No restrictions on $A_i,B_j$ and the dimension of $\rho$.

Comment: Well, then it is easy to cook up silly counterexamples: Take a product state tensor a maximally entangled state, and measure the Bell inequality on the former.

Comment: Thanks. But there exist $A_i$ and $B_j$ that violate the CHSH inequality in this case. I want to know if there always exist $A_i$ and $B_j$ that violate the CHSH inequality when $\rho$ is distillable.

Comment: Wasn't this why Werner introduced Werner states?

Comment: Would you expand on this point? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms6297 has an introduction which touches on a range of related questions.